# CollapsiblePanelExtender not showing content?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a page that contains 4 CollapsiblePanelExtenders ajax control that I switch witch one is open with java script. When I run this code on IE10 in Compatibility mode there is no problem and all works as expected however in IE10 without Compatibility mode, chrome and Firefox nothing at all appears on the screen

here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function LoadPanels() {
           var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
       Test1._animation._fps = 45;
       Test1._animation._duration = 0.5;

       var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
       Test2._animation._fps = 45;
       Test2._animation._duration = 0.5;

       var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
       Test3._animation._fps = 45;
       Test3._animation._duration = 0.5;

       var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
       Test4._animation._fps = 45;
       Test4._animation._duration = 0.5;

       SetPanel()

   }

   function SetPanel() {

       var OpenPanel = document.getElementById("<%=HFOpenPanel.ClientID %>")


       switch(OpenPanel.value)
       {
       case '0':
            var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
            var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
            var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
            var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
            Test1.set_Collapsed(false)
            Test2.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test3.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test4.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test4.set_Collapsed(true)


        break;
    case '1':
            var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
            var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
            var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
            var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
            Test1.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test2.set_Collapsed(false)
            Test3.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test4.set_Collapsed(true)

   break;
   case '2':
            var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
            var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
            var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
            var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
            Test1.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test2.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test3.set_Collapsed(false)
            Test4.set_Collapsed(true)
   break;
   case '3':
            var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
            var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
            var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
            var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
            Test1.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test2.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test3.set_Collapsed(true)
            Test4.set_Collapsed(false)
   break;
     default:
         var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
         var Test2 = $find("<%=CPEMenu2.ClientID %>")
         var Test3 = $find("<%=CPEMenu3.ClientID %>")
         var Test4 = $find("<%=CPEMenu4.ClientID %>")
         Test1.set_Collapsed(false)
         Test2.set_Collapsed(true)
         Test3.set_Collapsed(true)
         Test4.set_Collapsed(true)

         break;
      }
   }

   </script>
```

and the html of the first panel which should be open by defult

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFOpenPanel" runat="server" Value="0"  />
        <div class="xstep_but"><img src="panle.png"></div>
        <cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CPEMenu" runat="server" TargetControlID ="pnlMainMenu1"  SuppressPostBack="false" >
        </cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMainMenu1" runat="server">

         <div class="form_box">
                <div class="form_left">
                    <h3>About You</h3>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <div class="form_lable">Flat / house number</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form_txt" name="houseno" value=" "><div id='Div1' class="error_strings"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <div class="form_lable">Postcode</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form_txt" name="postcode" value =" "><div id='Div2' class="error_strings"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <div class="form_lable">Telephone</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form_txt" name="telephone" value=" "><div id='Div3' class="error_strings"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="next_but">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IBStep1" runat="server" Text="Button"  
                            onclick="Next_but_click" 
                            ImageUrl="image.png"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

The java script is attached to the onload function of the asp:ImageButton in the code behind during page load (so that the javascript is triggered after the postback and this way the animation still plays while the panel is opening)

Can anyone tell me why this only works with IE10 in compatibility mode and nothing else and what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: an update, While debugging in the browsers that do not work I get an javascript error stating that CPEMenu can not be found? how is that possible when it finds it in older browsers and what do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Another update, I have fixed the javascript problem now (simply by moving my javascript code inside my update panel) but now the animation does not play while the panel is opening